# r - how do I print ggplot objects from a nested tibble in a reactable with expandable rows?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, nested, reactable

I have a tibble in R with nested rows and I created a `ggplot` object per row. I would like to print these graphics using `reactable`'s expandable rows feature.

I think an example will explain this best. I'll use `iris` for simplicity. First, we take `iris`, nest it by "Species", and then make a column called "plot" that contains ggplot objects:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)
library(ggplot2)

df = iris %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  nest_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(plot = list(
    ggplot(data, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(Species)
  ))
```

It is possible to make a reactable object on our dataframe that spits out a nested reactable when you click on any row:

```
reactable(df %>% select(Species), details = function(index) {
    reactable(df$data[[index]])
  }
)
```

BUT...I can't figure out how to do the equivalent thing for printing the "plot" column. For example, this doesn't work:

```
reactable(df %>% select(Species), details = function(index) {
    print(df$plot[[index]])
  }
)
```

I've poked around with some HTML things like `htmltools::img(df$plot[[index]])` but it's all not working.

Any thoughts?? Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I actually solved this without requiring `plotly` -- you can use `htmltools::plotTag`. (Who knew?) Check it out:

```
reactable(df %>% select(Species), details = function(index) {
  htmltools::plotTag(df$plot[[index]], alt="plots")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If we wrap with `ggplotly`, then it would work

```
library(plotly)
library(reactable)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
reactable(df %>% 
    select(Species), details = function(index) {
 ggplotly(df$plot[[index]])
})
```

-output

[image]